# My widget titles in palette such as (TexField,Layouts, Form Widgets, and Images & Media) are blank ,How can I fix this?178173

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-widget

I am using Eclipse to develop android applications on Mac Os ,however ,the graphical layout components's titles for the folders such as TextField, Form Widget, Layouts, and Images &Media have been disappeared from the palette ,so I have blank or empty title(no also subtitles for some of widget however, some of widget are shown ) since I installed Eclipse ,How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Switch your computer system language from your country language to ENGLISH! the widget folders in palette cannot read your country language only english ... Fixed to me